# dynamically add and remove buttons from the PSPDF kit in ios

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, ios6, pspdfkit

I'm working on `PSPDFKIT`,

I need the solution for `add and remove buttons` from annotation toolbar.

and I want to `change some default annotation images`.

can anyone suggest me how to resolve those problems ,thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

add custom button while initializing **PSPDFDocument** in **PSPDFViewController**

```
PSPDFBrightnessBarButtonItem * brightnessBtn = [[PSPDFBrightnessBarButtonItem alloc] initWithPDFViewController:self]; // PSPDFKIT native button

UIBarButtonItem * closeBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(close:)]; // Custom button with title.

UIButton * moonBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)]; // Custom button with image.
[moonBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon____.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];[moonBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(moonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem * moontab = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:moonBtn];
```

If it is Navigation bar -

```
  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems/rightBarButtonItems = @[brightnessBtn, closeBtn, moontab];
```

If it is Toolbar -

```
 [toolbar setItems:@[brightnessBtn, closeBtn, moontab]];
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where you get your `toolbar` object from? Is it `self.annotationToolbarController?.annotationToolbar` ?